# Two fragments hold by another fragment - findViewById returns null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-fragments, findviewbyid

I need help for my first Android application. I have a single activity with an Action Bar at the top and Navigation Tabs. Because of these navigation tabs I had to convert my Activities into Fragments.

So one of those Activities (which is now a Fragment) held two fragments, one ListFragment on the Left and a DetailFragment on the right, so that the user is able to select an item from the list and directly sees details on the right.

But now as the Activity has been transformed into the Fragment, it's the Fragment that holds the List- and the DetailFragment. This works fine until I want to change the DetailsFragment.

First of all, here is the code of the Fragment holding the other two:

```
public class BlackboardFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    }

}
```

Here is the fragment_layout.xml file (saved in layout-land):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/interfaces"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.60"
        class="org.fawkesrobotics.app.InterfaceFragment" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewer"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So, the ListFragment is named InterfaceFragment, here is the code:

```
public class InterfaceFragment extends ListFragment {

    boolean mDualPane;

//      some other code

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        create_list();

        View viewerFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewer);
        mDualPane = viewerFrame != null
                && viewerFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
        }
    }

//      some other code
}
```

This is, where it doesn't work. The Fragment actually shows the list (that is created in create_list() where the ListAdapter and everything else is set), but my problem is, that viewerFrame is null. I declared the id viewer in the xml file above, so I don't understand why he cannot find the id. Does it "belong" to the BlackBoardFragment or to my overall activity? Because in BlackboardFragment I also tried it with getActivity().findViewById and it worked. Why is InterfaceFragment not able to find it?

I also tested, if he really uses the fragment_layout.xml in layout-land and he does. So he should know the id viewer, but obviously doesn't.

If you need more code or the code from the DetailsFragment, I can post it.

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Comment: if you are calling it via getActivity it means you are calling the activity view not the fragment.
Also make sure that you are putting in the right method, since there is onCreate and onActivityCreated for Fragments, there is significant diferences between those so check wheter you want one or another.

Comment: Currently the SDK doesn't allow for Fragments within Fragments. I'm confused as to how BlackboardFragment was able to inflate that layout.

Comment: @oneilse14 I thought the same however I think he refers to the fragment within fragment, to the FragmentActivity.

Comment: But actually it works.. When I manually set mDualPane to true, everything works fine. He shows the InterfaceFragment on the left, I can click on all the items and he shows me the details on the right. It's just that the cannot find the ID..

Answer (score 1):

use FragmentManager to get Fragment......

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment)  getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested `Fragment`s are not supported by the Android SDK. That is, you can't have a "fragment within a fragment" in your Android application. Sorry.

### EDIT:

Nested `Fragment`s are now part of the official Android 4.2 SDK! Yay!

Comment: But actually it works.. When I manually set mDualPane to true, everything works fine. He shows the InterfaceFragment on the left, I can click on all the items and he shows me the details on the right.  It's just that the cannot find the ID..

Comment: All I know is that you can't have fragments within fragments... it says so in the documentation. If you want your app to work 100% correctly, your fragments need to be attached to activitys. I'm not sure why your code is apparently working but it's clearly not correct.

Comment: Is there then any way to attach the fragments to activities and still have my action bar with navigation tabs? I mean I just want to have my single activity with the navigation bar, and one of the fragments shall contain this dual-sided view. Isn't this possible?

Comment: Yes there is! To do it, you simply need to have your Activity control the navigation. Your fragments have nothing to do with this... they are independent of the navigation and are held by the Activity. Perhaps you could take a look at [this implementation](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html) in the API demos.

Comment: In the link to the API Demo they use TabHost, this is deprecated in Android 4. I wanna use the Action Bar with Navigation Tabs as this is the intendend way now. And what do you mean when you say that my Activity should control the navigation? Do you mean that the activity holding the Action Bar and the Navigation Tabs should contain the two fragments for my two-sided view instead of one fragment holding two others?

Comment: `TabHost` is not deprecated since Android 4... you are thinking of `TabActivity`. The deprecation warning about `TabActivity` states "you can use the v4 support library which provides a version of the Fragment API that is compatible down to DONUT." The link I gave you is exactly what you are looking for :). Using `TabHost` is perfectly fine.

Comment: The Activity should be the one in charge of the navigation. The actual fragments are completely independent... that is, they are just getting swapped in and out of the screen as the user touches the tabs. None of the fragment's internal implementation will have anything to do with the navigation. In the link I gave you before, all of this is basically done in the nested `TabManager` class.

Comment: But with the use of TabHost I still cannot use my Navigation Tabs, because the TabHost has nothing to do with the Action Bar, am I right? I think as I already have tab-swapping code (for the Navigation Tabs) I will extend it and use the code in the link as a pattern/template. Thanks! :)

Comment: The android 4.2 update comes with default support for nested fragments, also compatible:
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments